# MudBlazor - Toggle dark/light theme from AppBar

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a simple blazor site using Mudblazor. My mainlayout is simple so that it has the mudblazor theme provider, it also has an app bar and a side bar which are there own components.
I want to be able to switch between dark and light mode which i have done successfully by following the guidance on the Mudblazor site.

What i want to do now is move the MudSwitch to the AppBar so its always available.

I have tried, cascadingparameters and event calls backs but neither of them worked in their entirety, i could get values set and events called but i could never get theme change.

Can someone please assist me with what the correct approach is and how it can be done.

MainLayout.razor

```
@using demo.UI.Components
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode" Theme="_theme" />

<MudLayout>
    <AppBar />
    <SideBar />
    <MudMainContent>
        @*Body*@
        this is my content, blah blah

        <MudSwitch @bind-Value="@_isDarkMode" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ma-4" T="bool" Label="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />

    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

@code
{
    private MudTheme _theme = new();
    private bool _isDarkMode = true;
}
```

AppBar.razor

```
<MudAppBar Elevation="1" Dense="true">
    <NavLink href="/">
        home
    </NavLink>
    <MudSpacer />

    <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket" style="color: #059669;"></i>
</MudAppBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to handle the theme change in the `MainLayout` component and not other components.

Since you have `MudAppBar` in your own `AppBar` component, then the simplest way is to use two way binding using **Parameter** & **EventCallback**.

The child component `AppBar` will notify the parent component `MainLayout` whenever the dark/light mode switch is toggled. Then the parent component will change the `MudThemeProvider`'s `IsDarkMode` property.

Here's a demo of the code below.
[MudBlazor Snippet Demo](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkwyEmwvsvqsTPox)

##### AppBar.razor

```html
<MudAppBar Elevation="1" Dense="true">
    <NavLink href="/" >
        home
    </NavLink>
    <MudSpacer />
    <MudSwitch Value="@IsDarkModeToggle" ValueChanged="HandleToggleChanged" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ma-4" T="bool" Label="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
    <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket" style="color: #059669;"></i>
</MudAppBar>

@code{
    [Parameter] public bool IsDarkModeToggle {get;set;}
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> IsDarkModeToggleChanged { get; set; }
    async Task HandleToggleChanged(bool newToggleValue)
    {
        await IsDarkModeToggleChanged.InvokeAsync(newToggleValue);
    }
}
```

In the example for the `AppBar` above I use `Value` and `ValueChanged` instead of a `@bind` as I need to perform custom logic when the value is changed.

If you've configured the Parameters correctly and followed the naming convention of Blazor parameters i.e. MyParameter & MyParameter**Changed** and you don't need to perform other actions in the parent component then, you can directly `@bind` it to the same field that the `MudThemeProvider` is bound to. i.e. `_isDarkMode`. Now if anything changes the `MudThemeProvider`'s `IsDarkMode`, it will change the toggle correctly aswell.

##### MainLayout.razor

```html
@page "/__main"
<MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode" Theme="_theme" />
<MudLayout>
    <AppBar @bind-IsDarkModeToggle="_isDarkMode"/>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@open" Breakpoint="@breakpoint" Elevation="1" Variant="@DrawerVariant.Responsive" PreserveOpenState="@preserveOpenState">
        <MudDrawerHeader>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">My App</MudText>
        </MudDrawerHeader>
        <MudNavMenu>
            <MudNavLink Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Store</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Library</MudNavLink>
            <MudNavLink Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Community</MudNavLink>
        </MudNavMenu>
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent Class="pt-16 px-16">
        <MudContainer Class="mt-6">
            @*Body*@
            this is my content, blah blah
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
@code{
    private MudTheme _theme = new();
    private bool _isDarkMode = true;
    bool open = false;
    bool preserveOpenState = false;
    Breakpoint breakpoint = Breakpoint.Lg;

    void ToggleDrawer()
    {
        open = !open;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked exactly as required. What I had previously missed in one of my attempts was
<AppBar @bind-IsDarkModeToggle="_isDarkMode" />

Comment: NP, Glad it helped!